# Sluggishness after CV axle replacement

Tags: honda, civic, cv-axle

**Context**:

My Car- Honda civic coupe Lx / 2007 ; 113000 miles

I was getting a cranking noise from the front left wheel on doing full wheel turns. I took to the local auto repair shop and he said my CV axle is bad.

I got the CV axle changed along with a few other works, including a rear break realignment and a general alignment (which was required as the cv axle was replaced), etc.

After change: All noise is gone, turning is smooth, all good, but ...

**Problem**:

I started feeling a "drag". Its hard to explain, but its like if I let the gas go, I feel the retardation is more than it used to be before the work done.. and I have to apply more power to keep it constant.

I took it back to the shop, there the mechanic test drove it but said he couldnt find anything (they rechecked the brakes and the alignment as well). I cant blame him for that, but I know my car and I know something is not right. Somebody driving it for the first time may not feel it.

He said - may be since its a new CV axle, its taking time to "break-in"  (but I kindda didnt buy it :-) so this post ...)

**So the question:**

Is it normal for a new CV axle to show this kind of sluggishness?

**** Edit ***

I also should have mentioned, they also did change the spark plugs as they said Honda recommendation is a change at 80k and I'm already 113. So if that matters...

Comment: This is going in the comments because everyone will think I am insane. Is it an automatic? Did they work on anything involving electrical/Disconnected the battery? I bought a used car that refused to coast.  I checked out the brakes etc, everything was fine. Did a Battery Reset and Idle Relearn and it reacted completely differently. Here's my theory. If you disconnect the battery, and not give the vehicle time to learn idle, it will behave much differently. Another, possibly more likely point is that new brake pads sometimes drag for a few miles till they've bed-in.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Not the battery, but I should have included.. they also did change my spark plugs, as they said Honda recommend spark plugs change in 80k, and I'm running 113k.

Comment: And yes, it's an automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was a busted transmission! Got it rebuilt (cost me a fortune :()
The occurrence of the problem coincided with the CV axle thing got me thinking that way.

Answer (score 0):

No. A new CV axle should work perfectly as soon as it's installed, and all the clicking should be cured.

Does the car pull to one side or the other when driving on a straight road? How about when you apply the brakes? If so, that indicates brakes or alignment.

I'd recommend taking it to a local tire/suspension shop - they'll give it a look over for a minimal cost, and should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: No, I didn't experience any side pulls, however I suspected alignment and had them recheck. And they said everything was fine.